# ckEditor icons display as question marks

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, ckeditor4.x

Hi guys i am using ckEditor in Dynamics 365 CRM, all was good until the client asked that i add some additional functionality (highlighting text).

So i added the needed plugin in my solution together with the icons.

Now the icons do show and the functionality works great, but the icons show as question marks on the form as shown on the image bellow:
[image]

I made sure that the path to the icons is correct and that they were loading in the solution.

Any and all suggestions are more than welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Open developer toolbar in browser (F12) and inspect those elements. You will find a clue on what’s wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i already tried that and saw that the path to the image is correct. When i try to open the link that is set as background image i get the correct image that needs to be set.

Comment: Is it same experience with all other browsers? If yes then probably compatibility image format issue. What’s the file extension of icons?

Comment: the images are in PNG format, im using Firefox Developer Edition(it's the easiest to configure proxy on).